# Accelerating a point in two dimensions

Tags: python, numerical-methods, kinematics

I have the following Python code:

```
import math

x = 0
y = 0

acceleration = 10
angle = 0

vx = 0
vy = 0

time = 10
for _ in range(time):
    vx += acceleration * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    vy += -acceleration * math.sin(math.radians(angle))

    x += vx
    y += vy

print(x, y)
```

Which outputs:

`550.0 0.0`

This is not what the equation for displacement yields.

`(acceleration * time**2) / 2` = **500**

What am I doing wrong? I would like to solve the problem without using time; pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: why use a loop and complicate things

Comment: @Shubham Shaswat: Perhaps I should clarify: this is merely illustrative of the problem. In reality, I have an object which is updated every time step.

Comment: The formula is exact, while you make a linear approximation. (Serious) rounding errors are inevitable.

Comment: `angle` never changes; you can precompute  the sine and cosine outside of the loop.

Comment: @dedObed: This is not a rounding error. This is a logical error.

Comment: @chepner: A keen observation. Is it, however, useful to optimise useless code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to find the exact integral of velocity over time, where velocity itself is given implicitly as the integral of acceleration. And you try do so by the simplest method available: the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). Accumulating inaccuracies are inevitable.

On top of errors (imprecision) inherent to Euler method, your implementation has the error of updating variables in a sequential manner. i.e.: you combine past displacement with current velocity -- instead of with the corresponding past velocity. You should compute new values of each variable and update them at the same time. For example like this (omitting constants from your code):

```
import math                                                                                                                                                                                                        

acceleration = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                  
vx = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
x = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                              

for _ in range(10):                                                                                                                                                                                                
    new_x = x + vx                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    new_vx = vx + acceleration                                                                                                                                                                                     

    x = new_x                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    vx = new_vx                                                                                                                                                                                                    

print(x) # 450
```

In your current setup (with the fix), the simulation runs like this:

[image: Simulation of the OP's implementation]

You can get better result by increasing the time resolution, e.g. by making steps of 0.1 instead of 1, you get:

[image]

If you're interested in better numerical integration methods, follow wikipedia to [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) or [Adams-Bashfort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method).

Here is the code to reproduce the plots:

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                                    

acceleration = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                  

t0 = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
t1 = 10                                                                                                                                                                                                            
nb_steps = 11                                                                                                                                                                                                      

ts = np.linspace(t0, t1, num=nb_steps)                                                                                                                                                                             
vs = np.zeros_like(ts)                                                                                                                                                                                             
xs = np.zeros_like(ts)                                                                                                                                                                                             

vs[0] = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
xs[0] = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                          

true_xs = acceleration * ts ** 2 / 2                                                                                                                                                                               


for i, t in enumerate(ts):                                                                                                                                                                                         
    if i == 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        continue # initial conditions are preset                                                                                                                                                                   

    delta_t = t - ts[i-1]                                                                                                                                                                                          
    vs[i] = vs[i-1] + acceleration * delta_t                                                                                                                                                                       
    xs[i] = xs[i-1] + vs[i-1] * delta_t                                                                                                                                                                            

plt.figure()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
plt.plot(ts, vs, label='velocity')                                                                                                                                                                                 
plt.plot(ts, xs, label='displacement-sim')                                                                                                                                                                         
plt.plot(ts, true_xs, label='displacement-true')                                                                                                                                                                   
plt.legend()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
plt.show()
```

Comment: The semi-implicit or symplectic Euler method is also an order 1 method and in some situations like orbital mechanics qualitatively more correct than the explicit or implicit Euler methods. It is only a half of a half-step away from the Verlet method, which is even better for mechanical systems. So it is right to say that the question code failed to implement the explicit Euler method, but wrong to say that it is categorically wrong.

Comment: Thank you. This is an excellent answer. I had no idea there were methods to these things; I assumed they were precise. I have only one further thing to ask: In my code, when I set starting velocity to `vx = -acceleration * math.cos(math.radians(angle)) / 2` and `vy = acceleration * math.sin(math.radians(angle)) / 2`, I seem to get correct and precise (x, y) results (at the cost of incorrect velocity). Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `x` and `y` should be updated with average of `vx` initial and final
velocity and `vy` respectively.

As the

If  you want x and y for every time step you should do like this,

```
import math

x = 0
y = 0

acceleration = 10
angle = 0

vx = 0
vy = 0

time = 10

vx = (vx + acceleration * math.cos(math.radians(angle))*time)/2 #average of velocity
vy = (vy  -acceleration * math.sin(math.radians(angle))*time)/2 #average of velocity

for _ in range(time):

  x += vx
  y += vy

  print(x, y)
```

Comment: I have updated my request, in that I do not want to use 'time' to solve the problem. You did not answer the question "What am I doing wrong?" You just wrapped the equation for displacement in a loop.